# finding patterns in csv file

Tags: csv, awk

trying to sort a csv file based on the repeating rows

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{arr[$4,",",$5,",",$6,,",",$7,",",$8,",",$9]++}END{for (a in arr) printf "%s\n",  arr[a] "-->" a}' test.txt
```

Input file

```
a,b,d,1,2,3,4,5,6,y,x,z
k,s,t,1,2,3,4,5,6,t,z,s
a,b,k,1,4,5,5,5,6,k,r,s
```

Create a file with

```
a,b,d,1,2,3,4,5,6,y,x,z-->2
k,s,t,1,2,3,4,5,6,2,t,z,s-->2
a,b,k,1,4,5,5,5,6,1,k,r,s-->1
```

- where the last column contains the number of occurrences of the pattern of numbers that start in the 4th place till the 9th place.

Count and sort the duplicate lines

I got to the point that I have the patterns with the count - but I don't know how to add the rest of the columns to the line:

thank you for the support.

Comment: So, what are those numbers in the last column, counts or order numbers?

Comment: last column is -->count

Comment: Please define the idea of the pattern

Comment: Where does the sorting take part?

Comment: First of all, you seem to have some <comma>-issues `$4,",",$5,",",$6,,`. They are also not needed. The index you create is going to read `$4 "@,@" $5 "@,@" ...`. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: You seem to be adding a 10th column to the 2nd and 3rd output lines but not to the 1st output line. What is it and why don't they all get it?

Answer (score 0):

A solution where the data is read twice, on the first go the duplicates are counted and on the second outputed:

```
$ awk -F, '
NR==FNR {
    a[$4 ORS $5 ORS $6 ORS $7 ORS $8 ORS $9]++              # count
    next
}
{
    print $0 "-->" a[$4 ORS $5 ORS $6 ORS $7 ORS $8 ORS $9] # output
}' file file
a,b,d,1,2,3,4,5,6,y,x,z-->2
k,s,t,1,2,3,4,5,6,t,z,s-->2
a,b,k,1,4,5,5,5,6,k,r,s-->1
```

Comment: Nope, that's not it. Some mysterious numbers may appear in column 10 in the expected output in th op. I don't quite understand them.

Comment: let me check :-)

Comment: file file at the end are multiple files that can be processed?

Comment: sorry - not working I ran it - and nothing happens after running the command

Comment: when I remove the word "next" it shows a result - but not accurate:NR==FNR {
    a[$4 ORS $5 ORS $6 ORS $7 ORS $8 ORS $9]++
}
{
    print $0 "-->"  a[$4 ORS $5 ORS $6 ORS $7 ORS $8 ORS $9] }' 2.test
a,b,d,1,2,3,4,5,6,y,x,z-->1
k,s,t,1,2,3,4,5,6,t,z,s-->2
a,b,k,1,4,5,5,5,6,k,r,s-->1
 the first line is also should be counted as 2

Comment: _solution where the data is read twice_ Yes, `file` needs to be there twice.

Comment: There is no need to use `ORS` for your array index. You can just write `a[$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9]` which is equivalent to `a[$4 SUBSEP $5 SUBSEP $6 SUBSEP $7 SUBSEP $8 SUBSEP $9]` where `SUBSEP` is default set to `@`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Perl also. The file is read only once, so it will be faster. Check this out:

```
$ cat shimon.txt
a,b,d,1,2,3,4,5,6,y,x,z
k,s,t,1,2,3,4,5,6,t,z,s
a,b,k,1,4,5,5,5,6,k,r,s
$ perl -F, -lane ' $v=join(",",@F[3..8]);$kv{$_}{$v}=$kv2{$v}++; END { while(($x,$y)=each (%kv)){ while(($p,$q)=each (%{$y})) { print "$x --> $kv2{$p}" }}}' shimon.txt
a,b,k,1,4,5,5,5,6,k,r,s --> 1
a,b,d,1,2,3,4,5,6,y,x,z --> 2
k,s,t,1,2,3,4,5,6,t,z,s --> 2
$
```

Another Perl - shorter code

```
$ perl -F, -lane ' $kv{$_}=$kv2{join(",",@F[3..8])}++; END { for(keys %kv) { $t=join(",",(split /,/)[3..8]); print "$_ --> $kv2{$t}" } } ' shimon.txt
a,b,k,1,4,5,5,5,6,k,r,s --> 1
a,b,d,1,2,3,4,5,6,y,x,z --> 2
k,s,t,1,2,3,4,5,6,t,z,s --> 2
```

or

```
$ perl -F, -lane ' $kv{$_}=$kv2{join(",",@F[3..8])}++; END { for(keys %kv) { print "$_ --> ",$kv2{join(",",(split /,/)[3..8])} } } ' shimon.txt
a,b,k,1,4,5,5,5,6,k,r,s --> 1
a,b,d,1,2,3,4,5,6,y,x,z --> 2
k,s,t,1,2,3,4,5,6,t,z,s --> 2
$
```

Comment: Glad to hear that.. pls consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, reading Input_file single time only.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
{
  a[FNR]=$0
  b[FNR]=$4 FS $5 FS $6 FS $7 FS $8 FS $9
  c[$4 FS $5 FS $6 FS $7 FS $8 FS $9]++
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++){
    print a[i]" ---->" c[b[i]]
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of James Brown is a very simple double-pass solution which has the advantage that you don't need to store the file into memory but the disadvantage of having to read a file twice. The following solution will just do the inverse, read the file only ones but have to keep it into memory. To this end we need 3 arrays. Array `c` to keep track of the count, array `b` to act as a buffer and array `a` to keep track of the original order.

Furthermore, we will make use of multidimensional array indices:

> A valid array index shall consist of one or more <comma>-separated expressions, similar to the way in which multi-dimensional arrays are indexed in some programming languages. Because awk arrays are really one-dimensional, such a <comma>-separated list shall be converted to a single string by concatenating the string values of the separate expressions, each separated from the other by the value of the `SUBSEP` variable. Thus, the following two index operations shall be equivalent:
>
> ```
> var[expr1, expr2, ... exprn]
> var[expr1 SUBSEP expr2 SUBSEP... SUBSEP exprn]
> ```

The solution now reads:

```
{ a[NR] = $4 SUBSEP $5 SUBSEP $6 SUBSEP $7 SUBSEP $8 SUBSEP $9
  b[$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9] = $0
  c[$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9]++ }
END { for(i=1;i<=NR;++i) print b[a[i]],"-->",c[a[i]] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem resembles SQL pattern, you can use sqlite also. Check this out.

```
$ cat shimon.txt
a,b,d,1,2,3,4,5,6,y,x,z
k,s,t,1,2,3,4,5,6,t,z,s
a,b,k,1,4,5,5,5,6,k,r,s
$ cat sqllite_cols4_to_9.sh
#!/bin/sh
sqlite3 <<EOF
create table data(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12);
.separator ','
.import "$1" data
select t1.*, " --> " || t2.cw from data t1, ( select c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9, count(*) as cw from data group by c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9 ) t2
where t1.c4=t2.c4 and t1.c5=t2.c5 and t1.c6=t2.c6 and t1.c7=t2.c7 and t1.c8=t2.c8 and t1.c9=t2.c9;
EOF
$ ./sqllite_cols4_to_9.sh shimon.txt
a,b,d,1,2,3,4,5,6,y,x,z, --> 2
k,s,t,1,2,3,4,5,6,t,z,s, --> 2
a,b,k,1,4,5,5,5,6,k,r,s, --> 1
$
```